# Angular Flex-Layout, Conditional Style/class according to Screen Resolution

Tags: css, sass, conditional-statements, angular-flex-layout

According to this post https://www.angularjswiki.com/flexlayout/basics/
In the item **List of Available Breakpoints in Angular Flex Layout**

The Breakpoints are:
| breakpoint | breakpoint meaning | mediaQuery |
| -------- | - | -------------- |
| **xs** | extra small | ‘screen and (max-width: 599px)’ |
| **sm** | small medium | ‘screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 959px)’ |
| **md** | medium | ‘screen and (min-width: 960px) and (max-width: 1279px)’ |
| **lg** | large | ‘screen and (min-width: 1280px) and (max-width: 1919px)’ |
| **xl** | extra large | ‘screen and (min-width: 1920px) and (max-width: 5000px)’ |
| **lt-sm** | less than small medium | ‘screen and (max-width: 599px)’ |
| **lt-md** | less than medium | ‘screen and (max-width: 959px)’ |
| **lt-lg** | less than large | ‘screen and (max-width: 1279px)’ |
| **lt-xl** | less than extra large | ‘screen and (max-width: 1919px)’ |
| **gt-xs** | greater than extra large | ‘screen and (min-width: 600px)’ |
| **gt-sm** | greater than small medium | ‘screen and (min-width: 960px)’ |
| **gt-md** | greater than medium | ‘screen and (min-width: 1280px)’ |
| **gt-lg** | greater than large | ‘screen and (min-width: 1920px)’ |

**Is it possible with `FlexLayout` to apply some Style, or CSS class according to the Resolution?**

**NOTE:** sorry for the before text stackoverflow has a bug with MD table, in edition mode works fine!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use the breakpoints with

#### with [ngClass](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/ngClass-API):

```
<div class="text-md" ngClass.gt-md="text-lg" ngClass.gt-lg="text-xl"></div>
```

#### with [ngStyle](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/ngStyle-API):

```
<div style="color: blue" ngStyle.gt-lg="color: red"></div>
```

---

Or, depending on your use case, you can

#### Set up the fxFlex [breakpoints](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Responsive-API) in your scss:

```
// variables.scss or styles.scss
$xs: 'screen and (max-width: 599px)';
$sm: 'screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 959px)';
$md: 'screen and (min-width: 960px) and (max-width: 1279px)';
$lg: 'screen and (min-width: 1280px) and (max-width: 1919px)';
$xl: 'screen and (min-width: 1920px) and (max-width: 5000px)';
$lt-sm: 'screen and (max-width: 599px)';
$lt-md: 'screen and (max-width: 959px)';
$lt-lg: 'screen and (max-width: 1279px)';
$lt-xl: 'screen and (max-width: 1919px)';
$gt-xs: 'screen and (min-width: 600px)';
$gt-sm: 'screen and (min-width: 960px)';
$gt-md: 'screen and (min-width: 1280px)';
$gt-lg: 'screen and (min-width: 1920px)';
```

and use them like this:

```
// styles.scss or my.component.scss
@import 'variables.scss';
@media #{$gt-md} {
  .asdf {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

```
<!-- my.component.html -->
<div class="asdf"></div>
```